# How to define a rule in scrapy which crawls the website link recursively?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to build an application which uses `scrapy` to crawls a website to get all the links which are on homepage plus the links which can be reached using the homepage link.

But the problem is that i am not able to figure out how to set the `rules` in scrapy to get all the direct+indirect url from `start_urls`. I think the rules can be set to get through the recursive call to parse function which can parse the each page.

Please help. Code is attached below which is working fine but when i run it on one website it showed me only 10 urls (of homepage) while that website contain interlinked 100 URLs.

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "MySpider"

    def __init__(self, allowed_domains=None, start_urls=None):
        super().__init__()
        # self.name = name
        if allowed_domains is None:
            self.allowed_domains = []
        else:
            self.allowed_domains = allowed_domains
        if start_urls is None:
            self.start_urls = []
        else:
            self.start_urls = start_urls  


    #rules for recursively scraping the URLS found
    # rules = [
    #     Rule(
    #         LinkExtractor(
    #             canonicalize=True,
    #             unique=True
    #         ),
    #         follow=True,
    #         callback="parse"
    #     )
    # ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print('[parse] url:', response.url)
        # extract all links from page
        all_links = response.xpath('*//a/@href').extract()
        # iterate over links
        for link in all_links:
            print('[+] link:', link)
            #yield scrapy.http.Request(url="http://www.myntra.com" + link, callback=self.print_this_link)
            full_link = response.urljoin(link)
            yield scrapy.http.Request(url=full_link, callback=self.print_this_link)


    def print_this_link(self, response):
        print('[print_this_link] url:', response.url)
        title = response.xpath('//title/text()').get() # get() will replace extract() in the future
        text = response.xpath('//body/text()').get()
        yield {'url': response.url, 'title': title, 'text': text}


# --- run without creating project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file as CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', # 
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.crawl(MySpider, allowed_domains=["copperpodip.com"], start_urls=["https://www.copperpodip.com/"])

# c.crawl(MySpider, allowed_domains=["myntra.com"], start_urls=["http://www.myntra.com/"])
# c.crawl(MySpider, allowed_domains=["tutorialspoint.com"], start_urls=["https://www.tutorialspoint.com/"])

c.start()
```

Output of above code:

```
C:\Users\Carthaginian\Desktop\projectLink\crawler\crawler\spiders>python weblinkextractor.py
2019-08-20 17:23:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.7.3 started (bot: scrapybot)
2019-08-20 17:23:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.0.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 19.7.0, Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018), cryptography 2.5, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
2019-08-20 17:23:05 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
2019-08-20 17:23:06 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: edbceddaec9a0924
2019-08-20 17:23:06 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-08-20 17:23:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-08-20 17:23:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-08-20 17:23:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-08-20 17:23:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-08-20 17:23:08 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-08-20 17:23:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-08-20 17:23:08 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
2019-08-20 17:23:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 5963ea0dabdbdd3a
2019-08-20 17:23:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-08-20 17:23:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-08-20 17:23:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-08-20 17:23:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-08-20 17:23:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-08-20 17:23:08 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-08-20 17:23:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2019-08-20 17:23:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-08-20 17:23:08 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.203056,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 20, 11, 53, 8, 199642),
 'log_count/INFO': 19,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 20, 11, 53, 7, 996586)}
2019-08-20 17:23:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2019-08-20 17:23:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/> (referer: None)
[parse] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com
2019-08-20 17:23:11 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.copperpodip.com> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/leadership
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/careers
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/contact-us
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/blog
[+] link: javascript:void()
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/ip-news
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/source-code-review
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/reverse-engineering
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/infringement-claim-charts
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/patent-monetization
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/due-diligence
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/prior-art-search
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/request-for-samples
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-source-code-review
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-due-diligence
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-infringement-analysis
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/leadership
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/blog
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/careers
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/contact-us
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/08/08/Patent-Alert-Amazon-wins-patent-for-spoilage-sniffing-refrigerator
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/05/20/Patent-Alert-Teslas-New-Patent-Application-Proposes-a-Sunroof-with-Electric-Tinting
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/30/Tokenization-Future-of-Payment-Security
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/25/Patent-Alert-IBM-Awarded-DLT-Patent-for-Data-Sharing-and-Validation
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/22/Patent-Alert-PayPal-Patent-Can-Protect-PCs-From-Ransomware-Attacks
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/12/The-Future-is-Green-Energy---HyperSolars-Environment-Friendly-Hydrogen-Generator
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/10/Patent-Alert-Sonys-Prescription-VR-Glasses
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/01/07/Making-Amends-Chinas-New-Intellectual-Property-Appeals-Court
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/12/18/Patenting-their-Newfangled-Spider-man-Sony
[+] link: #
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/blog
[+] link: https://www.siliconindiamagazine.com/magazine/patent-and-trademark-law-special-july-2018/#page=28
2019-08-20 17:23:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.siliconindiamagazine.com': <GET https://www.siliconindiamagazine.com/magazine/patent-and-trademark-law-special-july-2018/#page=28>
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/source-code-review
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/reverse-engineering
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/infringement-claim-charts
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/patent-monetization
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/due-diligence
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/prior-art-search
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/leadership
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/careers
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/contact-us
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/blog
[+] link: https://www.linkedin.com/company/copperpod-ip
2019-08-20 17:23:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.linkedin.com': <GET https://www.linkedin.com/company/copperpod-ip>
[+] link: https://www.copperpodip.com/privacy-policy
[+] link: mailto:info@CopperpodIP.com
2019-08-20 17:23:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com
2019-08-20 17:23:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com', 'title': 'Copperpod IP', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/leadership> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/leadership
2019-08-20 17:23:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/leadership>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/leadership', 'title': 'Leadership | Copperpod IP', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/ip-news> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/ip-news
2019-08-20 17:23:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/ip-news>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/ip-news', 'title': 'IP News Archives | Copperpod IP', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/careers> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/careers
2019-08-20 17:23:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/careers>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/careers', 'title': 'Copperpod IP | Careers', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/25/Patent-Alert-IBM-Awarded-DLT-Patent-for-Data-Sharing-and-Validation> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
2019-08-20 17:23:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/30/Tokenization-Future-of-Payment-Security> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
2019-08-20 17:23:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/contact-us> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/25/Patent-Alert-IBM-Awarded-DLT-Patent-for-Data-Sharing-and-Validation
2019-08-20 17:23:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/25/Patent-Alert-IBM-Awarded-DLT-Patent-for-Data-Sharing-and-Validation>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/25/Patent-Alert-IBM-Awarded-DLT-Patent-for-Data-Sharing-and-Validation', 'title': 'Patent Alert: IBM Awarded DLT Patent for Data Sharing and Validation', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/30/Tokenization-Future-of-Payment-Security
2019-08-20 17:23:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/30/Tokenization-Future-of-Payment-Security>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/30/Tokenization-Future-of-Payment-Security', 'title': 'Tokenization : Future of Payment Security', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/contact-us
2019-08-20 17:23:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/contact-us>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/contact-us', 'title': 'Copperpod IP | Contact', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/05/20/Patent-Alert-Teslas-New-Patent-Application-Proposes-a-Sunroof-with-Electric-Tinting> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/05/20/Patent-Alert-Teslas-New-Patent-Application-Proposes-a-Sunroof-with-Electric-Tinting
2019-08-20 17:23:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/05/20/Patent-Alert-Teslas-New-Patent-Application-Proposes-a-Sunroof-with-Electric-Tinting>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/05/20/Patent-Alert-Teslas-New-Patent-Application-Proposes-a-Sunroof-with-Electric-Tinting', 'title': "Patent Alert: Tesla's New Patent Application Proposes a Sunroof with Electric Tinting", 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-source-code-review> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
2019-08-20 17:23:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/request-for-samples> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-source-code-review
2019-08-20 17:23:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-source-code-review>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-source-code-review', 'title': 'Copperpod IP | Case Studies | Source Code Review', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/prior-art-search> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/request-for-samples
2019-08-20 17:23:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/request-for-samples>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/request-for-samples', 'title': 'Request Sample Reports | Copperpod IP', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/prior-art-search
2019-08-20 17:23:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/prior-art-search>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/prior-art-search', 'title': 'Copperpod IP | Prior Art Search', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/due-diligence> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
2019-08-20 17:23:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-infringement-analysis> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/due-diligence
2019-08-20 17:23:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/due-diligence>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/due-diligence', 'title': 'Technology Due Diligence  | Copperpod IP', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-due-diligence> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-infringement-analysis
2019-08-20 17:23:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-infringement-analysis>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-infringement-analysis', 'title': 'Copperpod IP | Case Studies | Infringement Analysis', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-due-diligence
2019-08-20 17:23:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-due-diligence>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-due-diligence', 'title': 'Copperpod IP | Case Studies | M&A Due Diligence', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/blog> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/blog
2019-08-20 17:23:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/blog>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/blog', 'title': 'Copperpod IP | Blog', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/08/08/Patent-Alert-Amazon-wins-patent-for-spoilage-sniffing-refrigerator> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/08/08/Patent-Alert-Amazon-wins-patent-for-spoilage-sniffing-refrigerator
2019-08-20 17:23:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/08/08/Patent-Alert-Amazon-wins-patent-for-spoilage-sniffing-refrigerator>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/08/08/Patent-Alert-Amazon-wins-patent-for-spoilage-sniffing-refrigerator', 'title': 'Patent Alert: Amazon wins patent for spoilage-sniffing refrigerator', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/patent-monetization> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/patent-monetization
2019-08-20 17:23:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/patent-monetization>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/patent-monetization', 'title': 'Patent Monetization | Copperpod IP', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/12/18/Patenting-their-Newfangled-Spider-man-Sony> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
2019-08-20 17:23:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/privacy-policy> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
2019-08-20 17:23:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/infringement-claim-charts> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/12/18/Patenting-their-Newfangled-Spider-man-Sony
2019-08-20 17:23:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/12/18/Patenting-their-Newfangled-Spider-man-Sony>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/12/18/Patenting-their-Newfangled-Spider-man-Sony', 'title': 'Patenting their Newfangled Spider-man : Sony', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/privacy-policy
2019-08-20 17:23:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/privacy-policy>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/privacy-policy', 'title': 'Copperpod IP | Privacy Policy', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/infringement-claim-charts
2019-08-20 17:23:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/infringement-claim-charts>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/infringement-claim-charts', 'title': 'Claim Charts | Copperpod IP', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/12/The-Future-is-Green-Energy---HyperSolars-Environment-Friendly-Hydrogen-Generator> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
2019-08-20 17:23:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/reverse-engineering> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/12/The-Future-is-Green-Energy---HyperSolars-Environment-Friendly-Hydrogen-Generator
2019-08-20 17:23:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/12/The-Future-is-Green-Energy---HyperSolars-Environment-Friendly-Hydrogen-Generator>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/12/The-Future-is-Green-Energy---HyperSolars-Environment-Friendly-Hydrogen-Generator', 'title': "Working Towards a Greener Future - HyperSolar's Environment Friendly Hydrogen Generator", 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/reverse-engineering
2019-08-20 17:23:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/reverse-engineering>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/reverse-engineering', 'title': 'Reverse Engineering | Copperpod IP', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/01/07/Making-Amends-Chinas-New-Intellectual-Property-Appeals-Court> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/01/07/Making-Amends-Chinas-New-Intellectual-Property-Appeals-Court
2019-08-20 17:23:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/01/07/Making-Amends-Chinas-New-Intellectual-Property-Appeals-Court>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/01/07/Making-Amends-Chinas-New-Intellectual-Property-Appeals-Court', 'title': "Making Amends : China's New Intellectual Property Appeals Court", 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/10/Patent-Alert-Sonys-Prescription-VR-Glasses> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
2019-08-20 17:23:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/22/Patent-Alert-PayPal-Patent-Can-Protect-PCs-From-Ransomware-Attacks> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/10/Patent-Alert-Sonys-Prescription-VR-Glasses
2019-08-20 17:23:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/10/Patent-Alert-Sonys-Prescription-VR-Glasses>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/10/Patent-Alert-Sonys-Prescription-VR-Glasses', 'title': "Patent Alert: Sony's Prescription VR Glasses", 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/22/Patent-Alert-PayPal-Patent-Can-Protect-PCs-From-Ransomware-Attacks
2019-08-20 17:23:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/22/Patent-Alert-PayPal-Patent-Can-Protect-PCs-From-Ransomware-Attacks>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/22/Patent-Alert-PayPal-Patent-Can-Protect-PCs-From-Ransomware-Attacks', 'title': 'Patent Alert: PayPal Patent Can Protect PCs From Ransomware Attacks', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.copperpodip.com/source-code-review> (referer: https://www.copperpodip.com/)
[print_this_link] url: https://www.copperpodip.com/source-code-review
2019-08-20 17:23:18 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.copperpodip.com/source-code-review>
{'url': 'https://www.copperpodip.com/source-code-review', 'title': 'Source Code Review | Copperpod IP', 'text': '\n            \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n    '}
2019-08-20 17:23:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-08-20 17:23:18 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (26 items) in: output.csv
2019-08-20 17:23:18 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 11536,
 'downloader/request_count': 27,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 27,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 3271917,
 'downloader/response_count': 27,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 27,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 20,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 10.421651,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 20, 11, 53, 18, 465151),
 'item_scraped_count': 26,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 56,
 'log_count/INFO': 14,
 'offsite/domains': 2,
 'offsite/filtered': 4,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 27,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 27,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 27,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 27,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 27,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 20, 11, 53, 8, 43500)}
2019-08-20 17:23:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Expected Urls in Output which i done using BeautifulSoup Library:

```
C:\CIP004\LinkExtractor>python extractor.py
Allowed Domain: ['https:', '', 'www.copperpodip.com']
Allowed name: .copperpodip.com
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/22/Patent-Alert-PayPal-Patent-Can-Protect-PCs-From-Ransomware-Attacks
https://www.copperpodip.com/prior-art-search
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2019-08
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/08/08/Patent-Alert-Amazon-wins-patent-for-spoilage-sniffing-refrigerator
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/12/18/Patenting-their-Newfangled-Spider-man-Sony
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/opinions
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/paypal
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/wan
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Gagandeep-Singh
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2018-03
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2018-01
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/code%20review
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Udbhav-Pant%2C-Naman-Arora
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/ecommerce
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/iot
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2018-05
https://www.copperpodip.com/due-diligence
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2017-04
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/technology

...
Number of Links Present in HomePage: 28
Number of Links Extracted: 189
```

Comment: Expected URLs has more URLs but stackoverflow allowing only 30k..

Answer (score 0):

Example Answer using BeautifulSoup - I have also tried some way using `BeautifulSoup`
code as below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.copperpodip.com"
# url = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm"

allowed_domain = url.split('/')
print("Allowed Domain: "+str(allowed_domain))
if(len(allowed_domain[2].split('.')) == 3):
    allowed_name_in_url = allowed_domain[2].lstrip(allowed_domain[2].split('.')[0])
else:
    allowed_name_in_url = allowed_domain[2]


print("Allowed name: "+str(allowed_name_in_url))

def links(url):
    html = requests.get(url).content
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    links = bsObj.select('a[href]')
    final_links = set()

    for link in links:

        url_string = link['href']

        if("https" in url_string or "http" in url_string and allowed_name_in_url in url_string):
            final_links.add(url_string)
        else:
            continue

    return final_links


extractedUrlList = []

def crawl(urls, seen=set()):
    for url in urls:
        if url not in seen:
            try:
                if(allowed_name_in_url in url):     
                    print(url)
                    extractedUrlList.append(url)
                    seen.add(url)
                    new_links = links(url)
                    crawl(urls.union(new_links), seen)
                else:
                    continue
            except:
                continue

starting_links = links(url)
crawl(starting_links)



print("Number of Links Present in HomePage: "+str(len(list(starting_links))))
print("Number of Links Extracted: "+str(len(extractedUrlList)))
```

output of above answer

```
C:\CIP004\LinkExtractor>python extractor.py
Allowed Domain: ['https:', '', 'www.copperpodip.com']
Allowed name: .copperpodip.com
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/22/Patent-Alert-PayPal-Patent-Can-Protect-PCs-From-Ransomware-Attacks
https://www.copperpodip.com/prior-art-search
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2019-08
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/08/08/Patent-Alert-Amazon-wins-patent-for-spoilage-sniffing-refrigerator
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/12/18/Patenting-their-Newfangled-Spider-man-Sony
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/opinions
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/paypal
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/wan
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Gagandeep-Singh
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2018-03
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2018-01
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/code%20review
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Udbhav-Pant%2C-Naman-Arora
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/ecommerce
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/iot
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2018-05
https://www.copperpodip.com/due-diligence
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2017-04
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/technology
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/12/06/The-future-is-transparent---Sonys-New-Smartphone-Patent
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/emergingtech
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/30/Tokenization-Future-of-Payment-Security
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/facebook
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/10/18/Facebook-and-other-social-networks-face-infringement-charges-over-GPS-based-patents
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/fake%20news
https://www.copperpodip.com/careers
https://www.copperpodip.com/code-reviewer
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/samsung
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/standards
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/amazon
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/licensing
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/lpwan
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2016-12
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/virtualreality
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/09/12/Tesla-Awarded-Brand-New-Battery-Patent
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/01/31/Active-Noise-Cancellation-Innovations-and-Applications
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Naman-Arora
https://www.copperpodip.com/business-development
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2016/12/22/Source-Code-Review-Best-Practices
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/google
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/judgments
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/10/18/iPhones-Shouldnt-Be-Banned-from-Sale-says-ITC
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2018-07
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/home%20automation
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2016-11
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/04/12/Microsoft-Hololens-First-Major-Update-Applications-and-More
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Udbhav-Pant
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/cryptography
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2018-02
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/lg
https://www.copperpodip.com/privacy-policy
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/08/06/LG-and-Ericsson-Sign-Global-Patent-Cross-Licensing-Agreement
https://www.copperpodip.com/patent-monetization
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/apple%20pay
https://www.copperpodip.com/technical-associate
https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-infringement-analysis
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/04/17/VirnetX-Awarded-5026-Million-in-Fourth-Jury-Trial-against-Apple
https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-due-diligence
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/blockchain
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/bluetooth
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/donald%20trump
https://www.copperpodip.com/ip-news
https://www.copperpodip.com/infringement-claim-charts
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/11/26/Marking-Every-Move---Googles-Home-Automation-Patent
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2018-09
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2018-10
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/GPS
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/5g
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Purva-Sharma
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/arista
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/02/16/Fake-News-Patents
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/social%20networks
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/09/30/Sonys-new-patent-claims-to-solve-VR-sickness
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/05/07/Decoding-Apple-Pay
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/telecom
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/China
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2018-11
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/11/14/Apples-LTPO-TFT-Technology-Promises-Prolonged-Battery-Life
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/11/13/Wave-of-the-future---The-Apple-Event
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Vedanshi-Nagar
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/paytm
https://www.copperpodip.com/source-code-review
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/05/03/Low-Power-Wide-Area-Network-Technologies-%25E2%2580%2593-Next-Step-for-the-IoT-ecosystem
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2017-01
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/microsoft
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/08/09/IBM-wins-82-million-from-Groupon-over-e-commerce-patents
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/LTPO-TFT
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/12/The-Future-is-Green-Energy---HyperSolars-Environment-Friendly-Hydrogen-Generator
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/07/09/Opinions-Bridge-the-Real-Gap-between-Academics-and-Industry
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/Tesla
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2017/01/10/standard-essential-patents-making-frands-and-foes
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/11/06/Happy-Diwali
https://www.copperpodip.com/leadership
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2016-10
https://www.copperpodip.com/case-study-source-code-review
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/source%20code
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2018-08
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/08/21/New-Security-Flaw-Discovered-in-Intel-Products---Ominously-Named-Foreshadow
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/08/03/Is-your-patent-expiring-Heres-how-to-calculate-patent-expiration-dates
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/greentech
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/electronics
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2018-04
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/duediligence
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/Apple
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/10/Patent-Alert-Sonys-Prescription-VR-Glasses
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/journalism
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/02/05/Are-plastic-straws-finally-on-the-way-out
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/networks
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/trademarks
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/electronics/page/1
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Shubham-Sehgal%2C-Lovjinder-Singh
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/Samsung
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2019-04
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/tradesecrets
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/software
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/Sony
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/10/18/Apples-new-Patent-will-keep-the-Spammers-away
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/11/12/Samsung-Galaxy-Note9--Explosion-Nightmare
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/08/06/Family-Federation-of-World-Peace-sues-World-Peace-and-Unification-Sanctuary-over-%E2%80%9C12-Gates-trademark
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/news
https://www.copperpodip.com/request-for-samples
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/uber
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2016/12/09/SCOTUSSamsungAppleVerdict2016
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2019-05
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/wifi
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/hypersolar
https://www.copperpodip.com/contact-us
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/apple
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/patents
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/patents/page/1
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/patents/page/3
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/patents/page/2
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2018-12
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/12/12/Swiss-Institutes-Outmatch-Oxford-and-Stanford-in-Patent-Quality
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/news/page/1
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/08/31/Deciding-Patent-Venue-How-TC-Heartland-Changed-the-Game
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/08/09/Arista-agrees-to-pay-400-million-to-Cisco
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/ibm
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/01/07/Making-Amends-Chinas-New-Intellectual-Property-Appeals-Court
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/fintech
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2016/12/26/PayPal-Accuses-Paytm-of-Trademark-Infringement-in-India
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/05/20/Patent-Alert-Teslas-New-Patent-Application-Proposes-a-Sunroof-with-Electric-Tinting
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/qualcomm
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2016/11/15/New-Approaches-to-Prior-Art-Search
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/page/6
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/page/4
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/page/3
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/licensing/page/1
https://www.copperpodip.com/reverse-engineering
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/china
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2017-03
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2017/03/16/Copperpod-IP-Sponsors-WIPF-2017
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/nokia
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/date/2019-01
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Gagandeep
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/hololens
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Rahul-Vijh
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/itc
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/cisco
https://www.copperpodip.com
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2016/12/26/Nokia-drags-the-world-back-to-war
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/09/30/Amazons-patent-that-puts-workers-in-cages
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/05/01/Opinions-Facebook-subverted-democracy
https://www.copperpodip.com/technical-intern
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/software/page/1
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2019/04/25/Patent-Alert-IBM-Awarded-DLT-Patent-for-Data-Sharing-and-Validation
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2016/12/22/Defensive-Code-Review-Fight-Fire-With-Fire
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/security
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/ericsson
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/sony
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/07/12/Apple-and-Samsung-Bury-the-Hatchet-Finally
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/page/2
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Arjunvir-Singh
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Arjunvir-Singh/page/3
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Arjunvir-Singh/page/2
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Arjunvir-Singh/page/1
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/author/Rahul-Vijh%2C-Gagandeep-Singh
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/07/24/Opinions-Blaming-Facebook-is-easy-but-wrong
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/page/1
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/internet%20of%20things
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/04/11/WPA3-Next-Gen-Security-for-Next-Gen-Internet-of-Things
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2017/04/18/Managing-Code-Risks-During-a-Software-Acquisition
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/education
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/08/06/claimchartspatentlitigationlicensing
https://www.copperpodip.com/single-post/2018/10/05/The-bystander-who-rattled-the-Waymo-Uber-settlement
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/intel
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/page/5
https://www.copperpodip.com/blog/tag/automobiles
Number of Links Present in HomePage: 28
Number of Links Extracted: 189
```